# Как называется технология, позволяющая делать такие сайты?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно сделать главную страницу сайта наподобие вот этих:

http://ru.wix.com/

https://vimeo.com/cameo

Где каждый блок контента меняется при прокрутке страницы, создается впечатление, что идет не прокрутка, а перелистывание страниц.
С прокруткой разобрался -- буду использовать ScrollMagic.
А как насчет div'ов, подстраивающихся под размер экрана (причем все сразу, но показываются по одному), и плавной прокрутки?

Answer (score 1):

Называется это все [LANDING PAGE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) или Целевая страница

Comment: Это понятно. Вопрос в том, с помощью чего это сделать удобнее.

Comment: @TheMatver цитирую ваш вопрос "Как называется технология, позволяющая делать такие сайты?"

Answer (score -7):

Это JavaScript! Серьёзно. Делаете модель, которая хранит состояния вашего сайта. Контроллеры, которые обрабатывают прокрутку, изменение размера экрана и т. п. диспатчат события, меняющие модель. Изменение модели слушают контроллеры, управляющие вьюхой, которая, в свою очередь, отвечает за отображение. PROFIT!!! Если вам нужно реализовать такой нешаблонный проект, то тут без MVC не обойтись.

Comment: что за технология javaScrip, вы ее сами себе придумали?

Comment: На фронте сейчас все спокойно обходятся без классического mvc с реактивным подходом.

Comment: @Утка, а что такое классическое mvc? А ещё очень интересно что такое реактивный подход, только не словами взятыми и заученными из книг, а простыми словами. А то очень смешно слушать когда именитые фраймворки выдумывают небылицы, как маркетинговый ход. И вдвойне смешней, когда те кто прочел добавляет что-то свое, делая ложь ещё слаще.

Comment: @OlmerDale, https://twitter.com/agento/status/790856622860013568

Comment: @Утка, я даже не понял к чему вы эти непонятные картинки показали. Если Вы учитесь по твиттерам, то пора что-то менять.

Comment: @OlmerDale, уже поздно. Твиттер научил меня не вступать в еще_один_спор_про_мвц если нет настроения и не слушать незнакомых дядь которые запрещают мне учиться по твиттерам.

Comment: Если бы это было так, то вы бы не показали мне эти бредовые картинки, а дали ссылку на первоисточник 1979 года, на настоящее классическое mvc (от слова классика). Но увы нет, Вы избрали путь маркетинга, суть которого не развитие, а продажи. И даже не думайте что они как и Вы программисты, они точно так же хотят кушать и готовы продать свою ужасно спроектированную идею, как лекарство от всех болезней.

Comment: Не надо так. Я не программист. Я утка.